# Python3 tk.Scrollbar and focus

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to put together a UI that has to present the user with a long list of input selections. I've put the input fields into a frame with a scroll bar and scrolling with the bar works. But when the user tabs out of the viewport the scroll bar doesn't automatically follow it.

The other problem I have is that the window is not sizing to fit the content; if I call `self.frame.grid()` after `populate()` the window does some odd stuff and sizes to content, but the scroll-bar no-longer works if the window is resized or if the number of lines of content exceeds the height of the screen. I want the window to be `min(maxSizeForRows, screenHeight)` and fixed width but not height.

I'd appreciate any help or pointers getting this to work.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Test(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root, borderwidth=0)
        self.root = root

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.yview)
        self.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", tags="self.frame")

        self.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.populate()


    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.configure(scrollregion=self.bbox("all"))


    def addRow(self, label, ent1, ent2):
        row = self.row

        lab = tk.Label(self.frame, text=label)
        lab.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky='W')

        sv = tk.StringVar()
        sv.set(ent1)
        e1 = tk.Entry(self.frame, width=16, justify=tk.RIGHT, textvariable=sv)
        e1.grid(row=row, column=1)

        sv = tk.StringVar()
        sv.set(ent2)
        e2 = tk.Entry(self.frame, width=16, justify=tk.RIGHT, textvariable=sv)
        e2.grid(row=row, column=2)

        self.row += 1


    def populate(self):

        self.row = 0
        for i in range(0, 10):
            self.addRow("Greeting", "Hello", "World")
            self.addRow("Parting", "Ciao", "Banana")
            self.addRow("Food", "Pepperoni", "Pizza")
            self.addRow("Drink", "Cold", "Beer")
            self.addRow("Actor", "Liam", "Neeson")
            self.addRow("Occupation", "Software", "Engineer")
            self.addRow("Languages", "Python", "Perl")
            self.addRow("Browsers", "Chrome", "Firefox")
            self.addRow("Places", "Irvine", "London")
            self.addRow("States", "Cali", "Texas")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Test(root=root)
    app.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I eventually got many of the behaviors I wanted by explicitly using grid AND pack at each level, but in return I also got the behavior that the scroll bar didn't work and the thing was hideously slow with lots of visible updates.

Comment: using grid and pack could not have helped. If you use both on the same widget, only the last one that you called will have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the issue with the tabbed-to widget being outside the viewport, you're going to need to add a binding to the entry widgets so that when they get focus the canvas is scrolled appropriately. This just requires a little math. It looks something like this:

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    # this makes it possible to scroll one pixel at a time
    self.configure(yscrollincrement=1)
    ...

def addRow(...):
    ...
    e1.bind("<FocusIn>", self.scroll_into_view)
    e2.bind("<FocusIn>", self.scroll_into_view)
    ...

def scroll_into_view(self, event):
    widget_top = event.widget.winfo_y()
    widget_bottom = widget_top + event.widget.winfo_height()
    canvas_top = self.canvasy(0)
    canvas_bottom = canvas_top + self.winfo_height()

    if widget_bottom > canvas_bottom:
        # subtract 4, because the frame is at 4,4 rather than 0,0
        delta = int(canvas_bottom - widget_bottom) - 4
        self.yview_scroll(-delta, "units")
    elif widget_top < canvas_top:
        delta = int(widget_top - canvas_top) + 4
        self.yview_scroll(delta, "units")
```

My math might be a tiny bit off, and there's a way to avoid hard-coding the `4` there, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

As for the resizing problem, if I understand you correctly then you need to bind on the `<Configure>` event of the canvas, so that when the canvas size changes, you change the width of the frame. That looks something like this:

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)
    ...

def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
    # subtract 8 to account for a border/margin
    self.itemconfigure('self.frame', width=self.winfo_width()-8)
```

You might need to tweak the constants to get precisely the right behavior, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Many thanks; I ditched the (4,4) to keep it simple, I'd picked that up from an example elsewhere and I guess I really don't need it. I wasn't able to resolve getting the scrollbar and/or sizing to all work seamlessly, so I ended up just setting a forced width and mixing grid and pack (which makes me balk). If you would be interested in seeing the actual implementation, http://bitbucket.org/kfsone/tradedangerous ... it's in the commands/update_gui.py.

Comment: @kfsone: calling `canvas.grid(...)` immediately followed by `canvas.pack(...)` doesn't do anything -- the call to `grid(...)` is simply ignored. Only one of `grid`, `pack` or `place` can control a widget at any one time, and the last one to be called wins. You also aren't setting the frame width when the canvas changes size like in my answer. You want to set the scrollregion when the _interior_ frame resizes, and you want to set the width of the frame when the _canvas_ resizes.